# <style> element in HTML visually disrupting a div INSIDE my <body> how?

Tags: html

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>DOM about</title>
        <!-- <style>
            .red {
            background: red;
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 2rem;
          }
          .blue {
            background: blue;
            color: white;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 2rem;
          }
          .title {
            background: blue;
            color: white;
            font-size: 3rem;
            text-transform: capitalize;
          }
          .btn {
            background: #f15025;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            border: none;
          }
          a {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 100vh;
          }
        </style> -->
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="list-items">
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When I run this code I get no issues on my live server concerning the displaying of my links on top of eachother in the div.

BUT when I uncomment the styles section my lists are suddenly spread around huge individual containers. I don't understand how that is possible. Can someone please clarify what context/syntax I am forgetting.

I just started learning how to code this week so forgive me if this is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the margin-top: 100vh; for a tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>DOM about</title>
        <style>
            .red {
            background: red;
            color: white;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 2rem;
          }
          .blue {
            background: blue;
            color: white;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 2rem;
          }
          .title {
            background: blue;
            color: white;
            font-size: 3rem;
            text-transform: capitalize;
          }
          .btn {
            background: #f15025;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            border: none;
          }
          a {
            display: inline-block;
            /* margin-top: 100vh; Thats the problem */
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="list-items">
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @c0d3r4ng0 you welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your links are spreading because you are giving margin-top: 100vh. So each a tag gets margin-top of 100vh. The problem is in the following place in style tag.

```
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100vh;
  }
```

Comment: Not a Problem. Happy to help.

Comment: Don' t do this. You approve my answer. Then you disapprove. It hurts. So, Please first think and then approve one answer.

Comment: I apparently can only approve 1 of the answers that I got. I wanted to approve both of your answers.

Comment: Oky I know. No problem. But I have said that please first think and then approved. Because it hurts when the reputation goes up and then suddenly go down.

Comment: I will know this for the future - sorry about that. And thank you again for taking your time to help!

Comment: No Problem. Thanks.